# Undefined property: stdClass::$comments

Tags: php, facebook

I am fairly new to programming and I was trying to make an image gallery by pulling the images from a facebook site as detailed here: http://www.webdesignermag.co.uk/tutorials/facebook-image-gallery/

but on the last page, where it is detailed what to do when there are no comments on the images, I get this:

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$comments in ...\getphotos.php
>   on line 95 No comments yet

The lines are:

```
    foreach ( $photoData->data as $data )
        {
            echo '<li><a href="'.$data->source.'" rel="lightbox" title="';
line 95 -->                if ($data->comments) {   
                    foreach ( $data->comments->data as $Cdata )
                        {
                            echo htmlentities('<li class="imgcomments">
                                              <a href="http://www.facebook.com/people/@/'.$Cdata->from->id.'"    target="_blank">                                                                             <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'.$Cdata->from->id.'/picture" align=left border=0 />
                                              </a>&nbsp;
                                              <a href="http://www.facebook.com/people/@/'.$Cdata->from->id.'" target="_blank">
                                              <b>'.$Cdata->from->name.'</a>: </b>'.$Cdata->message.'<br />
                                              <div align="left" style="padding-bottom:10px;">
                                              <small>&nbsp;Posted '.timeSince(strtotime($Cdata->created_time)).' ago</small></div>                                                   </li>');
                        }
                }
                else {
                    echo 'No comments yet';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property `comments` doesn't exist, so you cannot refer to it. Use [`property_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php) to find out if it does:

```
if (property_exists($data, "comments")) {
```